# How can I concatenate a file and string into a new file in UNIX as a one line command

Tags: unix, autosys

I need a very simple (hopefully) 1 liner command that reads in a file appends a string and outputs to a new file, without changing the original data.

```
file1               string
------              ------
apple               oranges
bananas
```

MAGIC COMMAND

```
filel               file2
------              ------
apple               apple
bananas             bananas
                    oranges
```

basically, cat file1 + 'oranges' > file2

I'm using **autosys** to run the command, and I'm pretty sure it doesn't allow for `&&` or `;` as part of a single command.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you provided?

Comment: cat thinks th + and 'oranges' are files and says it can't open them.

Comment: Can't you just cat file1 into file2 and then append the string? You can even execute both commands in a single line.

Comment: That's what I want to do, but I haven't figured out how. I've tried all sorts of variations on cat file1 > echo $string >> file2 but nothing works. So when you say "can't I?" I say, I'm sure I can, but I haven't figured out the actual command.

Comment: I came up with this: cp file1 file2 && echo 'oranges' >> file2

but I'm using autosys to run the command, and I'm almost certain it won't let me string commands together with &&

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can do this:

```
(cat file1 ; echo 'oranges') > file2
```

Which will spawn one subshell, which will cat file1 to stdout, then echo oranges to stdout. And we capture all that output and redirect it to a new file, file2.

Or these 2 commands:

```
cp file1 file2 
echo 'oranges' >> file2
```

Which first copies file1 to the new file2, and then appends the word oranges to file2

Here's another one liner that does not use ; nor &&

```
echo oranges | cat file1 - > file2
```

Comment: Yeah, I had come up with that one too, but because I'm using Autosys to run the command, I don't think I can include semi-colons or && in the command.

Comment: @Christian: Do they really need to be a single line? Can't you put the two commands in a shell script and run it?

Comment: @Christian Better figure out what kind of commands you can run in autosys. Or use the last approach here, which runs 2 consecutive commands.

Comment: @tudor: I could very well create a shell script and do it. But thanks to work, it adds more work to get things into different environments, so a one liner would be best.

Comment: @nos: Can't do && and can't do ; in the command. Pipe and std_out are allowed though

Comment: @Christian Then use the last one-liner I just edited. If that's no good, your task would already be finished if you did write a small shell script to overcome the limitations of autosys

Comment: @nos: Writing the shell script is easy.

Using the script as a solution at my workplace adds extra paperwork that I want to avoid. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Then this should do it:

```
$cat file1 >> file2; echo "orange" >> file2;
```

Comment: No, first file should remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '1; END{ print "oranges"}' file1 > file2
```

You can probably use the standard solution (given by nos) if you pass it as a string to sh:

```
sh -c 'cat file1; echo oranges' > file2
```